# Multiple datepicker disabling previous date is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Looks like this code has made a promise not to work in my code. What i am trying to do is i have two date-picker. When i click on Date1 i want to disable all the previous date of the month. On selecting a date2 i want to disable all the previous date of date1. I can't understand what i'm missing here. any help please?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  $( "#enddate" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $("#enddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
    }
  });
$("#enddate").datepicker({});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
 <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="enddate"></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can't assign a `minDate` to an object that has not yet been initialized.

Comment: Why you are initializing datepicker twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
  });
  $("#enddate").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(date) {
    $("#enddate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
  });
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
  });
  $("#enddate").datepicker({
    minDate: $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  });
});
```

The latter I suspect will be better.

Comment: Thanks Twisty i've solved the problem. but i need another solution. I want the date format as dd/mm/yy i tried this code to have that : $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date())); but i can't understand where to put it . i am newbie in jquery.. would you help me to fix it ?

Comment: I hope my post helped answer your question. If it did, please upvote and mark it as the answer. In regards to your other question, I would advise you to search for this, as there are examples: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats if you still cannot find an answer, post a new question with a full example of your current code.